# --target=node6 equivalent for React SSR?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, parceljs

I need two compiles to achieve server-side rendering with React. I have spent many days trying and it does not work. With Parcel 1 it worked perfectly. My problem is that after compiling it tells me that Node does not recognize the css that it is going to send to the client. In parcel I just put --target = node6 and everything worked great. Help !!

**Here is my actual package.json:**

[image]

Here is the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
dist-server/index.css:1
.line-total{border-top:2px solid #0}
```

Comment: Guessing based on the error you're seeing, it sounds like node is choking when it tries to run a js file that has an import/require call that points to a `css` file. Can you share a full repro?

Comment: Hi, here is my repo:

I would appreciate your help infinitely

Comment: https://github.com/ruballos/parcelrssr

Comment: run "npm run build"

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of an onion-peeling exercise to get everything working, but I think I found the source of the first issue, and I can give you some tips about where to go from there.

Here's an overview of what is happening:

1. Your `build:server` command is telling parcel to bundle your server located at `server/index.js`
2. Your `server/index.js` file has a line that imports your client app code:

   ```
   import App from '../src/App.js';
   ```
3. `App.js` imports a `.css` file.

So when you go to run the server bundle with node, the first thing it does is try to `require("ouput-css-file.css")`, which chokes because it's not javascript.

You could fix this first layer of errors by instead importing the `.css` file in your `src/index.html` instead of `src/App.js`:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./App.css"></link>
```

That should get you past the problem mentioned in your question, but it looks like you'll hit another layer of (unrelated) errors in your `server/index.js` file - you need to correctly reference the `../dist` files from the client bundle output, and actually import the `renderToString` method, were the first that I hit, but it keeps going.

You might want to take a step back and try to get the server code working without `parcel` (while still using `parcel` to generate the client bundle) and then addd parcel back to the server build process after you're sure you've got it working.